# When Can You State that a Given Class is a Set?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Just wondering if the following is of any interest (I am an amateur in these areas, so this might be so much malarkey).

Let $\mathcal X$ be a class in ZFC set theory. Let $\mathbb \Phi:\mathcal X \to \mathcal X $ be a defined bijective correspondence with the property that for every $X \in   \mathcal X$, $\mathbb \Phi(X) \ne X$. Then $\mathcal X$ is a set.

> Question 1: Can the above statement even be formulated in ZFC?
>
> Question 2: If if does make sense, is it true or could it be used in
>   an axiomatc framework?

Comment: Incidentally, by far the simplest criterion for set-hood is: a class $\mathcal{X}$ is a set iff it contains only elements of *bounded rank in the cumulative hierarchy*, that is, iff there is some ordinal $\alpha$ such that every element of $\mathcal{X}$ is in $V_\alpha$. One direction is obvious by separation, and the other direction follows since $(1)$ the class of ranks of elements of a set is always a set and $(2)$ no unbounded class of ordinals is a set (take the union).

Comment: What's nice about this is that it establishes the class $Ord$ as the minimal proper class, in a precise sense. If $\mathcal{X}$ is a proper class, then we can define a surjection from $\mathcal{X}$ to $Ord$: send $a\in\mathcal{X}$ to the Mostowski collapse of the set of ranks of elements of $\mathcal{X}$ less than the rank of $a$ itself. Meanwhile, there are models of ZFC in which there is no definable (even with parameters) surjection from $Ord$ to $V$, so this is a nontrivial fact. On the other hand, the ideal result - that $Ord$ in fact *injects* into any proper class - doesn't always hold.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in ZF alone there may be *sets* to which $Ord$ does not definably surject - these will be *exactly* the non-well-orderable sets (if $f:Ord\rightarrow x$ is onto, for $a,b\in x$ we can set $a\triangleleft b$ if $min(f^{-1}(a))<min(f^{-1}(b))$; note that this uses the fact that $Ord$ is well-ordered). So the axiom of choice is equivalent to the existence of a surjection from $Ord$ to every set. Okay fine this isn't expressible in set theory, but an appropriate version of it is, namely "For every set $x$ there is a set $a$ of ordinals and a surjection from $a$ to $x$."

Comment: @noah Funny that the simplest criterion doesn't sound that weird! It seem intuitive, and in these matters you can expect some 'way out' arguments.

Comment: Yes, one of the nice features of ZFC (or indeed ZF, or indeed Z+[a bit more]) is how much it simplifies the set/class issue. Telling whether a class is a set is much harder in, say, Quine's set theory NF (or its variants), but in ZF-style set theory everything boils down to just **rank**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the principle you're considering is **false**: consider the class $\mathcal{X}$ of ordinals which are either limits or successors of limits. Then there is an obvious self-bijection of $\mathcal{X}$ with no fixed points - namely, for $\alpha\in\mathcal{X}$ we send $\alpha$ to $\alpha+1$ if $\alpha$ is a limit and we send $\alpha$ to the predecessor of $\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is not a limit - but $\mathcal{X}$ is a proper class since no unbounded class of ordinals is a set.

Another example which may be easier to think about at first: let $\mathcal{A}$ be the class of all sets of the form $x\times\{0\}$ and let $\mathcal{B}$ be the class of all sets of the form $x\times\{1\}$. Their union $\mathcal{C}:=\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$ is clearly a proper class, but by swapping $0$ and $1$ we get a self-bijection of $\mathcal{C}$ with no fixed points.

---

As to expressing it appropriately, there is a serious problem: you can't quantify over class functions in set theory (that is, you can't say "for some $\Phi$"). What you *can* do is express the principle as a *scheme*: for each formula $\Phi$ defining a class function and each formula $\chi$ defining a class, we can write a sentence which says "$\Phi$ defines a fixed-point-free self-bijection of the class defined by $\chi$." However, this is enough to express what you want (ignoring its falsity for the moment), so it's not a huge problem.

Comment: I was going to give a more complicated counter-example with X=L (Godel's class) but yours is just obvious.

Comment: So in ZFC can we give an explicit formula for a bijection $f:V\to V$ with no fixed point?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Sorry, my previous comment was silly (I just got non-identity, not no-fixed-points). But the answer to your question is definitely **yes**. Here's one way (being a bit sloppy): say that a set $x\not\in V_\omega$ has *depth $n$* if $x$ can be written as $\{\{...\{a\}...\}\}$ for some set $a$ with more than one element, using $n$ pairs of curly braces. E.g. $\{\{\omega\}\}$ has depth $2$. For $x\not\in V_\omega$ let $\hat{x}=\{x\}$ if $x$ has even depth and $\{\hat{x}\}=x$ if $x$ has odd depth. The map $x\mapsto\hat{x}$ is a derangement of $V\setminus V_\omega$; now complete it.

Comment: My idea for a bijection $f:L\to  L,$ with no fixed points,employs the "canonical" well-ordering of  $L,$ but since this well-ordering can be used to define a bijection from $L$ to $On$ ( the Ordinals ) it is simpler, as you have done, to just take a bijection from $On$ to $On$ with no fixed points..... I don't understand your last comment. What is the depth of $\omega_1$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $\omega_1$ has depth $0$, so it would get swapped with $\{\omega_1\}$, which has depth $1$. $\{\{\omega_1\}\}$ would go to $\{\{\{\omega_1\}\}\}$, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is that if $\mathcal X$ can be bijected to itself with no fixed points, $\mathcal X$ is a set. The closest we can get to formulating this in ZFC is to introduce a unary predicate $\chi(x)$ meaning $x\in\mathcal X$ and a binary predicate $\phi(x,\,y)$ meaning $\Phi(x)=y$, and write (I hope I don't mess up the details!)$$(\forall x(\chi(x)\to\forall y,\,z(\phi(x,\,y)\land\phi(x,\,z)\to y=z\ne x))\land \exists y (\chi(y)\land \phi(y,\,x)))\to(\exists z\forall x(\chi(x)\leftrightarrow x\in z)).$$(Since ZFC's objects are all sets, "this is a set" means "there's a set with the members this has".) Note each choice of the predicates $\chi,\,\phi$ has its own version of this statement; we can't quantify over them in one statement, because the logic is first-order.

So that's question 1 answered. The conjecture isn't in general true, though. For example, let's biject the class of ordinals to itself according to the following rule: write an ordinal $\alpha$ as $\gamma+n$ with $n$ finite and $\gamma$ a limit ordinal; then $\Phi(\gamma+n)=\gamma+n+(-1)^n$. This doesn't have fixed points, but the ordinals don't form a set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be consistent with ZFC, but you can to the best of my knowledge formulate said condition in the language of sets (or in any other language), but it would require infinitely many axioms.

A class of sets is basically a family of sets given by a formula (possibly with parameters). You basically want to consider the following axiom for any pair or two formulas (possibly involving parameters) $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x,y,\bar{z})$, the first one having $1$ free variable and the second one $2+n$.

For every $\bar{a}$ (array of $n$ parameters), if $\psi(x,y,\bar{a})$ defines a bijection $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ with no fixed points, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the class defined by $\phi(x)$, then $\mathcal{X}$ is a set.

You can do this for every pair of formulas to formulate your condition.